# Books in Machine Learning via C/C++

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, references

I have been reading two excellent textbooks (Murphy, Mohri) in the machine learning. Although I am familiar with R and its utilization for ML, I was thinking of learning C/C++ via machine learning. There are quite many books that introduce the practical ML via R, Python, or Java, but I have not seen any book that introduce ML via C/C++....Is there a book or two (or any other resources) you know that does it? My plan is to learn C/C++ as I code for ML algorithms.

Comment: There is a C++ machine learning library called TMVA, part of the ROOT package, and it has documentation. However, I don't know how much it would help for learning.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hands-Machine-Learning-end-end-ebook/dp/B0881XCLY8

Answer (score 2):

For the statistics side (something like chapters 2, 4 of Murphy) you could get started with [Modeling with Data](http://modelingwithdata.org/about_the_book.html) by Ben Klemens.